# lein uberjar taking forever

Tags: clojure, uberjar

I want to create an uberjar of a leiningen app. My config is:

```
:uberjar {:omit-source true
             :aot :all
             :uberjar-name "myapp.jar"
             :source-paths ["env/prod/clj" ]
             :resource-paths ["env/prod/resources"]}
```

But upon doing `lein uberjar`, I find the the files in the project are being compiled, but the compilation is stuck on the file that contains most of the code, for ten minutes and counting. This file doesn't contain more than 140 lines.

Comment: My guess would be, that there is something def-ed at top level in that namespace, that has a side-effect.  E.g. some DB-connection or starting some server or whatever.

Comment: Yes, I just figured that this line: 
(defonce server
  (http/start-server server-handler {:port 8982}))

is causing the hang. How to fix this?

Comment: Don't put stuff like that at top-level. Write a function, that starts this server.  Then call that from your main.  For development you can run that function from the REPL or you can sprinkle some reload/restart logic in your user-ns. `defonce` only means it will not be re-def-ed once it's there.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: never `def` side-effects

---

As stated in the comments:

> ... I just figured that this line: `(defonce server (http/start-server server-handler {:port 8982}))` is causing the hang.

Don't put stuff like that at top-level.

`defonce` only means it will not be re-def-ed once it's there (so in this case
it would prevent some "port already in use" error on reloading.

#### Ways out of that dilemma

Write a function, that starts this server. Then call that from your main. For
development you can run that function from the REPL or you can sprinkle some
reload/restart logic in your user-ns.

Another option could be using `delay`: it will only execute the code once it gets `deref`ed.

The more "binding of resources" you have to deal with, the more some systematic
approach will give your application a better structure.  E.g. take a look at:

- [weavejester/integrant](https://github.com/weavejester/integrant)
- [stuartsierra/component](https://github.com/stuartsierra/component)
- [tolitius/mount](https://github.com/tolitius/mount)

#### So why is putting blocking things or side-effects in a `def` problematic?

The way the Clojure compiler works, is by actually "running" the code. So `compile` basically is:

1. enable generation byte code and write it out as .class files
2. load the namespace and "run" it

This means, that at compile time, the top level side-effects are executed.
Therefor blocking operations in a `def`, will block compilation (which is quite
obvious), or your CI server will fail to compile, because it can not connect to
the database etc.

A great explanation of how the code generation in Clojure works:

- [What Are All These Class Files Even About? And Other Stories - Gary Fredericks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Qm09YiUHTs)